# What's the meaning of buzziest?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

"Seasoned travellers, especially the sort that jet around the globe clutching laptops, know that certain words are to be avoided like the plague. This is because those who choose these words are masters of disguise : the service offered is the exact opposite of that indicated by the name used to describe it. Thus many flights described as “direct” are actually indirect, since they involve a stop, and a lengthy wait, in, say, Dallas-Fort Worth en route between Boston and Vancouver. Similarly, habitués of railways learn to shun any train claiming to be an “express” or “rapid”, since such services seem invariably to be the slowest (by design, not just by accident). Which perhaps make it fitting that some of the most seasoned travellers of all, management consultants, appear to have been inspired by just this sort of untruth-in-advertising. ***The buzziest*** among them now claim not just to be consultants, or advisers, or even experts. They are “thought leaders”."

Comment: It could have several different meanings.  A lot depends on the context.

Comment: Is it defined in an online dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Well it means the person who's always up to something.
You could also use it like : He is the buzziest among the group(celebrity group),he is always making the headlines.

It could mean lively, dynamic, energetic or vibrant etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "liveliest" is synonymous for the word "buzziest." It's generally an informal term.

Comment: Good answer. +1. I immediately thought of 'buzziest' being connected to 'busy'. But 'buzz' is, as you say, a matter of vibrancy or liveliness.

Answer (score 1):

The most buzzy.

This appears to be used for the informal [meaning](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/buzzy)

> lively, interesting, and modern.